# How to disable clicking Webbrowser, but still able to scroll WebBroswer

Tags: vb.net

I have a WebBrowser in my VB.net form. I want to disable from users clicking links in the Webbrowser, but still able to scroll the Webbrowser. 
I found this code but it locks up the whole WebBroswers so I can't click links or scroll, but I need to be able to scroll.

```
DirectCast(WebBrowser1, Control).Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the following property:

```
WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = False
```

A hacky work-around to change the address from code would be to turn AllowNavigation on again, but it requires a BeginInvoke to allow the navigation to take place before turning it off again:

```
WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True
WebBrowser1.Navigate("new web address...")
Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = False))
```

Comment: it won't go to another page when i change web address. Is there a way i can still do this and still be able to change web address.

Comment: @n.Mehta Updated the post.